# Is there a way to test android data binding expressions in layouts?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-databinding

With Android's new [Databinding library](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), you can write inline expressions within your xml layout. For example, you can set the visibility of a view as such:

```
<TextView
   android:text="@{user.lastName}"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:visibility="@{user.isAdult ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

How do I go about unit/layout testing this? I want to make sure that the visibility correctly toggles when user.isAdult is true and false.